# ResourceNotFound using InsertOrMerge : Azure Table Storage REST API

Tags: azure, rest, dart, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

**For insertOrMerge I know we should:**

> - If-Match, excluded from the header
> - Send merge request

I'm authorizing using SAS in the url

### Dart code:

```
String _urlString = '$endpoint($id)?$sas';

var url = Uri.parse(_urlString);

var request = http.Request('MERGE', url);
request.header = {
    "Accept": "application/json;odata=nometadata",
    "x-ms-date": DateTime.now().toUtc().toString(),
    "x-ms-version": "2020-10-02",
    "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  };
request.body = {
    PartitionKey: 'new key',
    RowKey: 'mykey'
};

request.send();
```

what am I missing?
knowing merge and also update works fine for me, but not for insertOrMerge neither insertOrUpdate

Comment: I have an other note here:
when setting 'x-ms-version' to the latest version : 2020-12-06
it complains cannot parse headers!! but all prior versions nothing wrong with them??!!

Comment: Can you try with the below request.body = {
    "PartitionKey": "new key",
    "RowKey": "mykey"
};

Comment: I don't see what you have to say!!

Comment: the key value pairs in the body should be in quotes

Comment: thanks a lot! I followed your advice but it didn't solve the problem.
rather it led me to it, see my answer.
it works on single quotes and on double quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dart
String _urlString = Uri.encodeFull('$endpoint($id)') + '?$sas';
```

this did the job, the problem was having unencoded characters in the url

- encoding sas modifies it; so it fails with AuthenticationFailed
- not using encodeFull on the first half (as a whole) of the url; fails with InvalidInput